# How i can insert KendoSlider to Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How i can include a kendo slider inside a kendo grid.

I am not able to insert it to the grid.

Is it possible to do this?.

Thanks & Regards,
Nithya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the slider in a column template. Then in the `dataBound` event of the grid initialize all sliders.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { foo: 1 },
    { foo: 2 }
  ],
  columns: [
    { 
      field: "foo", 
      template: "<input value='#= foo #' class='slider'>"
    }
  ],
  dataBound: function() {
    // Convert all <input class="slider"> to kendoSlider
    $("#grid .slider").kendoSlider();
  }
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ADigOFa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me lot.But is it possible  to make handler,the value fixed. events like a increament and decrement should not happen,in buttons.